# need to parse a string to json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

i have this following string to parse  as JSON and send as post request. not sure what is the best way to do this:

start=0&page_length=50&exclude_vehicle_category=%5B%5D&toll_non_toll=false&mode=%22detail_state_mileage_report%22&scope_kind=%22enterprise_group%22&scope_value=4317&scope_values=%7B%22enterprise_group%22%3A%204317%7D&start_date=%7B%22snap_unit%22%3A%20%22day%22%2C%20%22snap_direction%22%3A%20%22beginning%22%7D&end_date=%7B%7D&time_zone=%22EST%22&columns=%5B%22GROUPNAME%22%2C%20%22VEHICLEID%22%2C%20%22VEHICLENAME%22%2C%20%22VEHICLETAG%22%2C%20%22VEHICLE_VIN%22%2C%20%22TOTAL_DISTANCE_DRIVEN%22%2C%20%22TOTAL_DISTANCE_DRIVEN_OH%22%5D&coloring=%5B%5D&sort=%5B%5B%22GROUPNAME%22%2C%20false%5D%2C%20%5B%22VEHICLEID%22%2C%20false%5D%5D

Answer (score 2):

Say `s` contains your string:

```
hash = {}   
s.split("&").each do |key_value|
  key, value = key_value.split("=")
  hash[key.to_sym] = value
end
hash.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(s)
=> {"start"=>"0",
    "page_length"=>"50",
    "exclude_vehicle_category"=>"[]",
    "toll_non_toll"=>"false",
    "mode"=>"\"detail_state_mileage_report\"",
    "scope_kind"=>"\"enterprise_group\"",
    "scope_value"=>"4317",
    "scope_values"=>"{\"enterprise_group\": 4317}",
    "start_date"=>"{\"snap_unit\": \"day\", \"snap_direction\": \"beginning\"}",
    "end_date"=>"{}",
    "time_zone"=>"\"EST\"",
    "columns"=>"[\"GROUPNAME\", \"VEHICLEID\", \"VEHICLENAME\", \"VEHICLETAG\", \"VEHICLE_VIN\", \"TOTAL_DISTANCE_DRIVEN\", \"TOTAL_DISTANCE_DRIVEN_OH\"]",
    "coloring"=>"[]",
    "sort"=>"[[\"GROUPNAME\", false],[\"VEHICLEID\", false]]"
   }
```